# Calculating CPU usage of a cgroup over a period of time

Tags: cgroups, cpu-usage

If I have a cgroup like `user.slice` and have `CPUAccounting=true` set up, I'm wondering how one would calculate the CPU Usage of that particular cgroup over a period of time (such as 1s), using either `cpuacct.usage` or `cpuacct.stat`. I know `cpuacct.usage` [provides the CPU time](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/cpuacct.txt) (in nanoseconds), which could be used to calculate the CPU percentage by subtracting two snapshots of it during a period of time and dividing it by the total CPU time of the system over the same period of time (correct me if I'm wrong), but I'm unsure how to get the total CPU time over a period of time.

Is there a way I can get the total CPU time over a period of time or use a different formula/cgroup feature to calculate the CPU Usage? Thanks in advance :)

**Note:** I am aware of `systemd-cgtop`, which provides some of this information, however I want to calculate the CPU Usage programatically without having to parse `systemd-cgtop`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CPU usage percentage is the ratio of the total time the CPU was active, to the elapsed time of the clock on your wall. If you try and compare one CPU time to another CPU time, this isn't usage percentage. There is no name for this, it's just the ratio of one CPU time to another CPU time.

You've already stated you know how to get elapsed CPU time (by taking the difference of CPU time before & after your period), so just divide that by wall clock time.

```
cgroup=$(awk -F: '$2 == "cpu,cpuacct" { print $3 }' /proc/self/cgroup)

tstart=$(date +%s%N)
cstart=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/$cgroup/cpuacct.usage)

sleep 5

tstop=$(date +%s%N)
cstop=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/$cgroup/cpuacct.usage)

bc -l <<EOF
($cstop - $cstart) / ($tstop - $tstart) * 100
EOF
```

If you want to avoid the call to `date` (and `cat`), you could use something like: `read tstart _ < /proc/uptime`.

Comment: I love this answer in its simplicity, and probably my favorite which includes the SO forum. Worth noting your time diff matches the granularity of `cpuacct.usage`.

Comment: @phemmer Any help on cgroup v2 as it doesn't have cpuacct.usage?